# "to a degree" vs. "to an extent"

Tags: phrases, writing-style, connotation

Is there a measurable difference in meaning between the phrases "to a degree" and "to an extent" (or "to some degree" and "to some extent")?

Examples:

- To [some degree / some extent] that is a better solution.
- To [a degree / an extent], she is correct.

Just a matter of a style, or are there different connotations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say: simply style, when not in a geometrical context. Similarity or difference is being metaphorically expressed as distance, whether angular or linear.

Comment: A minor point: I am not sure *degree* necessarily refers to angular degree, as the word is used in many other contexts unrelated to goniometry. It basically just means a step, from Latin *gradus* step, both as in taking a step forward and as with the steps of a flight of stairs.

Comment: @Cerberus: I sit corrected! :^)

Answer (score 3):

*Extent* means "the amount to which something is or is believed to be the case," and *to a degree* means "to some extent."

There is no difference between the phrases, except (maybe) the position they take in a sentence.

> Everyone will have to compromise to some extent.
>   They altered the document to such an extent that it contained little in the way of new policy.
>   To a degree, it is possible to educate oneself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I've heard the difference explained: You have a glass of water with a drop of poison. If you drink any of the water, you will die. The *degree* of poison in the cup is only 1, yet the *extent* of the poison is 100%.