# "to what extent" vs. "to what level"

Tags: differences, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“to a degree” vs. “to an extent”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16150/to-a-degree-vs-to-an-extent)

What's the difference between "to what extent" and "to what level"? Please support your answer with examples.

Answer (score 3):

"*To what extent* was the area flooded?" asks how much of the area was flooded.

"*To what level* was the area flooded?" asks how deep the water was.

The metaphoric usage would mean more or less the same thing:-

"*To what extent* have you studied physics?" asks how many topics you have studied in physics, or how long have you spent doing so.

"*To what level* have you studied physics?" asks how advanced your studies were.

Comment: Although, in AmE *to what extent* is more common; at least metaphorically.