# "what that amounts to" vs. "to what that amounts"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, syntactic-analysis

> It is clear that A degrades the value of B but it is not clear **to what such degradation amounts**.

I am trying to say that the degradation is for sure but we are not sure what [the amount of] that degradation *exactly* is. "Amounts to" might as well mean "of what sort/character". So it is not just about the degree or amount. The second sense is essential in my sentence.

I assume the usage of "amounts to" in that sense is idiomatic. If not, please let me know.

But my main question is whether using it in the above form is idiomatic. Due to some biases, I couldn't find reliable examples of such a usage on the web, and some principal sources ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amount-to-sth), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amount-to), and [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amount%20to)) do not give such examples.

If you think such a usage is not idiomatic or is ambiguous, I appreciate your suggestion of verbs to replace "amount".

Comment: Since I'm not completely convicted of my answer, I shall not post it as an answer but a comment. I don't think *what such* sounds correct as you phrased it; maybe it is grammatically, but not idimatically, it sounds quite weird even for a non-native speaker's ears. I think, by that phrase, you meant something like: It is not clear to what kind of degradation amounts, if so, I do think that rephrasing it to: *It is not clear to what type of degradation amounts* will make it sound way better.

Comment: *Convinced* not *Convicted*, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: "...but it is not clear to what degree." Degradation is understood, and need not be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

@anongoodnurse provided the answer in the [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407437/what-that-amounts-to-vs-to-what-that-amounts#comment970126_407437) “"...but it is not clear to what degree." Degradation is understood, and need not be repeated.”

The following question  ["to a degree" vs. "to an extent"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16150/to-a-degree-vs-to-an-extent), posted in 2011, provided the impetus for me to hunt a little further.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20what%20degree) has an entry for the expression

> **to what degree**
>   how much
>
> - *To what degree is she interested in finance?*
>
> **degree**
>   a step or stage in a process, course, or order of classification

M-W adds an interesting note on the root ***grad***

> ### [Word Root of degree](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degree)
>
> The Latin word *gradus*, meaning “step” or “degree,” gives us the root **grad**. Words from the Latin *gradus* have something to do with steps. Anything ***grad***ual happens slowly one step at a time. To *de**grade*** is to reduce from a higher to a lower degree. A **grade** is a step in school made up of one year of work. Even the word *de**gr**ee* itself has *gradus* as its root.

Comment: That is a good suggestion but "to what degree" does not seem to have all what "amount to" has. "Amount to" may also mean "of what exact sort/character". And that is why I put "the amount of" in []. I want a word that has the second meaning too. The best choice is "amount to" itself but with that structure it gets weird when "to" goes before "what".

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> It is undeniable that A degrades the value of B but **to what extent** remains  uncertain/unclear.

The OP could substitute the last clause with

> It is clear that … **is currently under debate**

Oxford Living Dictionaries defines the phrase as:

> ### [under debate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/under_debate)
>
> Being discussed or disputed

Comment: Most generally, I want to change "A amounts to B" to an indirect question such as "I want to ask to what A amounts.". Do you know of any alternative ways to say both sentences.

Comment: @Sasan  You need to clarify the question. I'm sorry but if my answers haven't helped it means I haven't understood the problem.

Comment: I clarified it as a separate question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407942/indirect-question-using-the-verb-amount-to

Comment: @Sasan If I were writing, I'd say:  1. *What does XYZ mount to?* 2. *How much does XYZ amount to?* but they mean two different things. You need to add detail in your questions, what exactly do you want to say? Can't you provide some sort of  CONTEXT? *Real* content, real sentences? Maybe tomorrow when I'm less tired, I'll understand more.

Comment: I want both meanings together at the same time in the same sentence. Can the sentence have both meaning at the same time when I say "What does A amount to"?