# Indirect question using the verb "amount to"

Tags: indirect-question

> A amounts to B.

Which of the following is the correct form of indirect question related to the above sentence?

> 1) Could you tell me **to what A amounts**?
>
> 2) Could you tell me **what A amounts to**?

The first form is rarely found. [(Source)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20that%20amounts%20to%2Cto%20what%20that%20amount&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20that%20amounts%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20what%20that%20amount%3B%2Cc0) Is it incorrect, though? Plus the second form is ending with a preposition, and that is usually avoided by good writers.

Answer (score -1):

Both forms are generally accepted as grammatical, with the first form being more proper, formal, rare and awkward in casual conversation. The second form is far more common, even though it ends with a stranded preposition.

Comment: The first one sounds awkward because it blends formal and informal style. A more natural way of saying it would be *please tell me to what A amounts,* and by *natural* I mean my grandmother might actually say it.